# How to send part of the data through the pipe/file and later interactively?

Tags: pipe, stdin, expect

I have a command I want to run, let's call it `program`. It is an interactive program similar to bash or python REPL.

I want to start this program with some predefined input. I tried `program << "some_commands"`. But after executing `some_commands` it finishes and I cannot continue interacting manually.

If this program was bash I would use `.bashrc` for this purpose.

What is the correct way to use such a program with the predefined starting input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also do this without using expect:

```
{ echo foo ; cat ; } | command
```

Answer (score 3):

`expect` is the tool for this job:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn program
expect "I'm ready for input"
send "command 1\r"
expect "I'm ready for input"
send "command 2\r"
# ...
send "command last\r"
interact
```

The `interact` command returns control to the user.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [rlwrap](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/) to interact with your program. Rlwrap provides a line editor based on the readline library, the same that bash uses. This is typically not as good as the line editor provided by programs that do provide one (e.g. you won't get any syntax coloring or completion), but it's a lot nicer than the default terminal interface which understands only backspace.

```
rlwrap -P 'some_commands' program
```

The text is passed into the input buffer but not sent to the program, so you'll have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after starting the program. The whole text is passed as a single string. It can contain newlines.